# python3: csv.writer how to remove end of line ^M?

Tags: python-3.x, export-to-csv

I realized that  every end of line of my export.csv file ends with ^M, 
Any idea how to remove it?
Probably I have to modify somehow csv.writer 
When I import this csv file to SQL, I got one extra  NULL column at the end of row. :(

I read csv to array with  this code:

```
datafile = open('source.csv', 'r')
datareader = csv.reader(datafile, delimiter=',')
...
```

and then write to another csv file with this code

```
with open('export.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerows(data2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
with open('export.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL, lineterminator='\n')
    spamwriter.writerows(data2)
```

add `lineterminator='\n'` as parameter like above in the csv.writer() method to specify the new line terminator character.

Answer (score 0):

You should open the source file with `newline=''` instead so that the original newline endings can be preserved for `csv.reader` to handle newlines properly:

```
datafile = open('source.csv', 'r', newline='')
```

Excerpt from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id3):

> If `newline=''` is not specified, newlines embedded inside quoted fields
>   will not be interpreted correctly, and on platforms that use `\r\n`
>   linendings on write an extra `\r` will be added. It should always be
>   safe to specify `newline=''`, since the `csv` module does its own
>   (universal) newline handling.

Comment: I added newline='' but still there is ^M in the end.
FYI: for creating new object data2 I use this code located btw read and write csv> `data2 = copy.deepcopy(data)`